# how to disable enhanced tooltips of windows ribbon

Tags: ms-office, vsto, ribbon

I'm new to VSTO development need to add a  customized ribbon.

I need to disable "enhanced tooltips" from Power Points VSTO project. currently I'm using "SuperTip" and "ScreenTip". Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a trick done by Microsoft to differentiate third party addins and Microsoft inbuilt functions 
if you go to properties(in vsto  project)--> publish -->options--> office settings  you could give a mean full something instead of solution name.